# How to show div on hover of a image?

Tags: html, css

i have some code like this....

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 "  style="vertical-align:top;">
  <img src="images/url.jpg" class="banner_img" />
  <div class="banner_caption">
    <h3>Banner caption here</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css like this...

```
.banner_caption{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-60px;
    display:none;
    left:0;
    color:#fff;
    transition-delay:1s;
    transition:all 1s;
}

.banner_img:hover .banner_caption{
    bottom:0px;
    display:block;
}
```

banner_caption div should appear when I hover on the image...
but I am unable to do that....anyone having ideas to solve this?

Comment: `banner_img:hover .banner_caption` - this means that `banner_caption` is nested inside the `banner_img`, which is not the case, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks a lot....it worked great...thumbs up

Answer (score 3):

Just give this:

```
.banner_img:hover + .banner_caption
```

The plus (`+`) is called sibling selector.

```
.banner_img:hover + .banner_caption{
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

The reason behind why yours doesn't work is:

- `.banner_img:hover .banner_caption`: `.banner_caption` is inside the `.banner_img`.
- `.banner_img:hover + .banner_caption`: `.banner_caption` is adjacent to the `.banner_img`.

So you need to use the second one above.